# get all data from webservice. no parameters asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

i have an asp.net / c# web application and i was given a webservice that gives me all the info about a client. all i got to do is call the method and pass the client id and i get all his info. i wanted to get a list of all clients using that same method but if i dont pass a id it gives me an error. do you guys know of any way to do this?

i call it like this:

```
webservice.method(id);
```

i tried to do it like this:

```
webservice.method();
```

but it gives me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web service would have to be designed to allow the method to be called without any parameters. It doesn't happen automatically. Talk to the publisher of the web service to possibly get support for this.

Comment: i told them that and they said that if i searched i would find a way of doing it. whatever guess i'll have to talk to them again

Comment: @aconstancio Or just check out support for the API and see if they have such a method.

Comment: @aconstancio, I guess they want you to call the service in a loop sending id one by one and constructing the list at your end. This answer is rightly saying that it can't be done automatically.

Comment: i thought about that. i kinda explained wrong because it isn't a ordinary id so i cant really make a cycle getting every id's info 1 by 1 or whatever. every client has a total random GUID

Comment: as @AndrewBarber mentioned, are there any other methods that this service calls that may offer this functionality?

Comment: @aconstancio Is it possible this service does not *want* you to enumerate other entities?

Comment: initially i wasnt supposed to. but since i finished everything they asked for so much earlier than expected i wanted to innovate and asked them if it was possible to list every client using that same webservice, they said it was but didnt want to tell me how and said that if i searched a bit i'd find a way of doing it. guess i'll just find something else to add to my web application then.

Comment: Cam Bruce. the only clients method is the one im trying to use. everything else is for products and other stuff